# Why is this SQL Server stored procedure considered to have incorrect syntax (Error 102)?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linqpad, where-in

Trying to create a stored procedure in LINQPad 4, I get

> Error 102: Incorrect syntax near 'CHOPHOUSE'

I changed this line from an earlier stored procedure:

```
where up.Unit = @Unit
```

...to this:

```
where up.Unit IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO', 'ROCK BOTTOM')
```

What's wrong with it? Virtually the same thing:

```
WHERE UNIT IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI 2 DAYS', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO', 'ROCK BOTTOM')
```

...runs fine in a query in LINQPad. What could be the issue?

### UPDATE

Okay, y'all asked for it; the entire stored proc is:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_DontSleepInTheSubwayDarlin]
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @SortBy varchar(20) 
AS
DECLARE 
@SQLstring varchar(max), 
@Statement varchar(8000), 
@ShortName varchar(50),
@ItemCode varchar(25), 
@PriceWeek varchar(30),
@LastPriceWeek varchar(30),
@Week int, 
@WherePriceWeek varchar(2000), 
@Price varchar(25),
@Contractprice int,
@CalendarBegDate datetime,
@CalendarEndDate datetime

create table #Temp
(
    Unit varchar(50),
    ShortName varchar(25),
    ItemCode varchar(50),
    Description varchar(250),
    regionorder int,
    Contractprice varchar(50),
    Price varchar(25),
    Variance varchar(25),
    PriceWeek varchar(50),
    Week varchar(10)
)


-- create temp table
Select up.Unit, mm.ShortName,
up.ItemCode, Description=(Select Description from MasterProducts where ItemCode=up.itemcode), 
mm.regionorder, up.Contractprice 
into #TempContract From UnitProducts up 
Inner Join Unitmembers um on up.Unit=um.Unit and abs(um.pricesheet) = 1
Inner Join Members mm on um.memberno = mm.memberno
where up.Unit IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO', 'ROCK BOTTOM') 


Select @CalendarBegDate = C.BeginDate From Calendar C where @BegDate between C.BeginDate and C.EndDate
Select @CalendarEndDate = C.EndDate From Calendar C where @EndDate between C.BeginDate and C.EndDate

-- get weeks and where clause
SET @WherePriceWeek = ' Where '

Declare GetPriceWeek Cursor For
Select [PriceWeek] = C.Description, C.BeginDate 
From Calendar C 
where C.BeginDate <= @CalendarEndDate and C.EndDate >= @CalendarBegDate  
Order By 2 
Open GetPriceWeek
fetch next from GetPriceWeek into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin       
        Select @Statement = ('Alter Table #TempContract Add [' + @PriceWeek + '] numeric(8,2) ')
        exec (@Statement)
        IF(@WherePriceWeek<>' Where ')
        Begin
            SET @WherePriceWeek = @WherePriceWeek + 'or '
        End
        SET @WherePriceWeek = @WherePriceWeek + 'IsNull(['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' '
        fetch next from GetPriceWeek into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
    end
Close GetPriceWeek
Deallocate GetPriceWeek


-- build member data by weeks
Declare GetMemberColumns Cursor For 
SELECT distinct ShortName,ItemCode
FROM #TempContract 
Order by ShortName,ItemCode
Open GetMemberColumns 
fetch next from GetMemberColumns into @ShortName,@ItemCode
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        Declare GetMemberPrice Cursor For
        Select [PriceWeek] = C.Description, convert(varchar(20),
        cast(IsNull(mp.Price,0) as numeric(8,2))) as Price, 
        up.Contractprice 
        From MemberPrice mp 
        Inner Join UnitProducts up on mp.unit=up.unit and mp.itemcode=up.itemcode 
        Inner Join Unitmembers um on mp.memberno=um.memberno and mp.unit=um.unit and abs
(um.pricesheet) = 1
        Inner Join Members mm on mp.memberno = mm.memberno
        Inner Join Calendar C on mp.CYear=C.CYear and mp.Cweek=C.CWeek
        where mp.Unit IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO', 'ROCK BOTTOM') and C.BeginDate <= @CalendarEndDate and C.EndDate >= @CalendarBegDate 

and mm.ShortName = @ShortName and Mp.ItemCode = @ItemCode
        Open GetMemberPrice 
        fetch next from GetMemberPrice into @PriceWeek,@Price,@Contractprice
        while @@fetch_status = 0
            begin
                Print(@Price)
                Select @Statement = ('Update #TempContract Set [' + @PriceWeek  + ']=''' + 

IsNull(@Price,'0.00') + ''' where ItemCode=''' + @ItemCode + ''' and Unit IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO', 'ROCK BOTTOM') and 
[ShortName]=''' + @ShortName +'''')
                exec (@Statement)
                fetch next from GetMemberPrice into @PriceWeek,@Price,@Contractprice
            end
        Close GetMemberPrice
        Deallocate GetMemberPrice

        fetch next from GetMemberColumns into @ShortName,@ItemCode
    end
Close GetMemberColumns
Deallocate GetMemberColumns


--Select * From #TempContract 


-- final select statement
SET @Week = 0
SET @LastPriceWeek = ''
SET @SQLstring = ''

Declare SetPriceWeekSQL Cursor For
Select [PriceWeek] = C.Description, C.BeginDate 
From Calendar C 
where C.BeginDate between @CalendarBegDate and @CalendarEndDate 
Order By 2 
Open SetPriceWeekSQL
fetch next from SetPriceWeekSQL into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        SET @Week = @Week + 1 
        IF(@SQLstring='')
        Begin
            SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'Insert Into #Temp Select Unit, ShortName, ItemCode, 

Description, regionorder, Contractprice, IsNull('+
            '['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') as Price, (convert(decimal(10,3),''-0.001'')) as 

Variance, 
            '''+@PriceWeek+''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From 

#TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek

            IF(@SortBy='Members')
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, ShortName, '''', 

''zzzz'', '''', '''', ''0'' as Price, ''-0.001'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar

(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek
            End
            Else
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, '''', ItemCode, 

Description, ''1000'', Contractprice, ''0'' as Price, ''-0.001'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, 

''WK'+convert(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek
            End
        End
        ELSE 
        Begin
            SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION '
            SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'Select Unit, ShortName, ItemCode, Description, 

regionorder, Contractprice, IsNull('+
            '['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') as Price, IsNull(convert(decimal(10,2),['+@PriceWeek

+'])-convert(decimal(10,2),['+@LastPriceWeek+']),''0.00'') as Variance, 
            '''+@PriceWeek+''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From 

#TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek

            IF(@SortBy='Members')
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, ShortName, '''', 

''zzzz'', '''', '''', ''0'' as Price, ''0'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar

(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract Where IsNull(['+@LastPriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' or 

IsNull(['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' '
            End
            Else
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, '''', ItemCode, 
Description, ''1000'', Contractprice, ''0'' as Price, ''0'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert
(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract Where IsNull(['+@LastPriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' 
or IsNull(['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' '
            End
        End
        SET @LastPriceWeek = @PriceWeek
        fetch next from SetPriceWeekSQL into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
    end
Close SetPriceWeekSQL 
Deallocate SetPriceWeekSQL 

Print(@SQLstring) 
Execute(@SQLstring)

Drop Table #TempContract 

IF(@SortBy='Members')
Begin
    Select 
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        convert(varchar(20),convert(decimal(10,2),Price)) as Price,
        sum(convert(money,Variance)) as Variance,
        VarianceAverage = convert(varchar(25),convert(decimal(10,2),(Select sum(convert

(money,Variance)) From #Temp Where ShortName=T.ShortName and Week=T.Week) / Replace(((Select count

(regionorder) From #Temp Where ShortName=T.ShortName and Week=T.Week)-count(Variance)),'0','1'))), 
        PriceWeek,Week
    From #Temp T
    Group By
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        Price,
        PriceWeek,Week  
    Order By Week,ShortName,Description
End
ELSE
Begin
    Select 
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        convert(varchar(20),convert(decimal(10,2),Price)) as Price,
        sum(convert(money,Variance)) as Variance,
        VarianceAverage = convert(varchar(25),convert(decimal(10,2),(Select sum(convert

(money,Variance)) From #Temp Where ItemCode=T.ItemCode and Week=T.Week) / Replace(((Select count

(regionorder) From #Temp Where ItemCode=T.ItemCode and Week=T.Week)-count(Variance)),'0','1'))), 
        PriceWeek,Week
    From #Temp T 
    Group By
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        Price,
        PriceWeek,Week  
    Order By Week,Description,regionorder 
End

Drop Table #Temp
```

Comment: Can you include the entire stored procedure?  Looking at snippets is a little hard.

Comment: So the procedure never hits `'ROCK BOTTOM'` ?

Comment: On a more serious note, what is `Unit`? If it is a number that could be one manifestation of the comparing numbers to letters issue.

Comment: How does this question keep getting upvotes? It is not at all clear in the current manifestation. it is missing nearly all the details required to offer any real help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the lines of code you have posted.  The error must be in another part of the query.

Comment: @JohnPasquet: I added the entire SP to an Update above

Comment: @MaxSorin: "Unit" is a VarChar

Comment: In such long query if i get any syntax error then I always comment rest of the line except top few line,then one by one I uncomment rest lines to see which line causes the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

these lines:

```
IsNull(@Price,'0.00') + ''' where ItemCode=''' + @ItemCode + ''' and Unit IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO', 'ROCK BOTTOM') and 
[ShortName]=''' + @ShortName +'''')
```

There are not enough `'''` in them.

Also this procedure is 'ROCK BOTTOM'.

Edited should read:

```
 IsNull(@Price,'0.00') + ''' where ItemCode=''' + @ItemCode + ''' and Unit IN (''CHOPHOUSE'', ''CRAFTWORKS SC'', ''GORDON BIERSCH'', ''OLD CHI FRANCHISE'', ''OLD CHICAGO'', ''ROCK BOTTOM'') and 
    [ShortName]=''' + @ShortName +'''')
```

I'm no where convinced that my edit is going to fix everything that's wrong with the SQL.

Further I would probably look for way to remove as much of the string-to-SQL execution as possible. I can't do that here without asking for your credit card number as it would be too much work.

Comment: You beat me to it. It was the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Where are more needed/what should it be? On looking closer at it, ISTM that actually the four at the end could be eliminated, but I don't see where others are needed anywhere...

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - you need to double-quote each of the hardcoded values so they'll turn into single-quotes in the dynamic statement.